# Hibernate domain versioning when oneToMany relation is updated

Tags: hibernate, version, hibernate-onetomany

I am wondering if domain version will be changed if oneToMany relation is updated.
e.g There is User entity which has OneToMany relation to Addresses . So if I am updating Addresses list will it have impact on user version ?

```
@Entity public class User {
    @Id @Column(name = "id") 
    @GeneratedValue 
    private Long id; 

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "document") 
    public Set<Addresses> userAddresses; 

    @Version @Column(name="OPTLOCK") 
    public Integer getVersion() { ... } 
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the code and the definition of the tables `User` and `Addresses` that you are working on?

Comment: I don`t have code , I was asked this question during interview. Just Imagine there is @Entity public class User{ @Id @Column(name = "id") @GeneratedValue private Long id; @OneToMany (mappedBy = "document") public Set<Addresses> userAddresses; @Version @Column(name="OPTLOCK") public Integer getVersion() { ... } }

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not have any impact on the parent's version. You should explicitly force the parent version increment; see [LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html#OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT).

Comment: Thanks for the answer !